# Accumulate and Emit behaviour in RxJava 2

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, reactive

I have a `Status` class representing some task status. I have a method with the following signature

`def update(existing: Status, update: Status): Status`

The function takes old status and new update and returns a new `Status` object combining these two.

The behaviour I want from my custom subject is the following:

- Write Behaviour

  - It should hold an instance of `Status`. Let's call it `current`
  - I should be able to subscribe to a given `Flowable<Status>`
  - On each new Status Update (coming via the above `Flowable`), it'll call the `update` method as mentioned above and store the result in `current`.
- Read Behaviour

  - Periodic Read, Should be able to emit current status periodically. Something like `Flowable.interval(1 second).map(i->current)`

I'm able to achieve the above using a `StatusHolder` class for write behaviour (which does the holding and updating) and a separate subscription to `Flowable.interval(1 second).map(i->holder.current)`.

After implementing this, I came across the concept of `Subject`, which is both an `Observable` and `Observer`. The functionality I want is similar to this. I want a class which can both receive and emit `Status` Objects but needs to do some computation while receiving.

I've looked at existing `Subject` implementations and I don't think any of them naturally support this behaviour. Second thing is, they operate on `Observable`, not `Flowable`, so I need to do `toFlowable` and `toObservable` to use that.

Is there a better way of implementing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Let's define `source` as your source `Flowable<Status>`.

```
Flowable<Status> source = ...
```

Then you can try this:

```
Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .withLatestFrom(source.scan(this::update), (i, status) -> status)
        .share();
```

- `.interval()` operator periodically emits a long value.
- `.scan()` operator "accumulates" items emitted by the source stream. In your case the accumulator is `.update` function
- `.withLatestFrom()` combines two streams. This replaces your `.map(i->holder.current)`
- `.share()` allows all subscribers to share a single subscription.

A small side note:

There is a `Flowable` version of `Subject`, called `Processor`.